# How do I calculate time difference between timestamps in the same column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle database where bots are processing claims.  I have the bot id, claim id, and process timestamp.  I need to calculate the time a bot goes from one claim to the next claim.  I will then need to show the bots that take more than 5 minutes between claims, and the claim id of the beginning claim.  As an example:

```
Bot ID     Claim ID       Process Timestamp
123        12345          2/19/2018 12:45:26
123        12346          2/19/2018 12:55:11
```

The bot took more than 5 minutes processing claim 12345 so I will need to show:

```
Bot ID     Claim ID       Minutes
123         12345         9:85
```

Comment: The lead and lag windowing functions may be of use in solving this issue.

Comment: could you provide sample creation code for your database and the code you already tried?

Comment: I did not create database, and I am actually using two tables to get the base information of bot id, claim id, and process timestamp.  I have not yet figured out how to calculate time differences between one column.  I have searched online and found information on two columns, or columns that have an additional field of start time and end time, but none of that exists here.  Basically code for base is select distinct u.user_id as BotID, c.claim_id, c.process_timestamp from claim  c join user u on c.user_id = u.user_id where u.user_id like 'Bot%'

Answer (score 2):

You can use the analytic form of `lag()` to look at the previous row for a bot ID, where you define 'previous' in the window clause as being based on the timestamp. So:

```
select bot_id, claim_id,
  process_timestamp - lag(process_timestamp)
    over (partition by bot_id order by process_timestamp) as elapsed
from your_table;

    BOT_ID   CLAIM_ID ELAPSED             
---------- ---------- --------------------
       123      12345                     
       123      12346 +00 00:09:45.000000
```

Subtracting one timestamp from another gives you an interval, which you can't format directly, but you can extract its elements and stick them together as a string:

```
select bot_id, claim_id,
  extract(minute from elapsed) || ':' || extract(second from elapsed) as minutes
from (
  select bot_id, claim_id,
    process_timestamp - lag(process_timestamp)
      over (partition by bot_id order by process_timestamp) as elapsed
  from your_table
)
where elapsed > interval '5' minute;

    BOT_ID   CLAIM_ID MINUTES   
---------- ---------- ----------
       123      12346 9:45
```

Or if a claim could go beyond an hour:

```
select bot_id, claim_id,
  (60 * extract(hour from elapsed)) + extract(minute from elapsed)
    || ':' || extract(second from elapsed) as minutes
from (
...
```

---

If the column is actually a date not a timestamp, then the subtraction gives a number rather than interval. Converting that to a string can be done simply by adding that fraction of a day to a nominal date at midnight:

```
select bot_id, claim_id, to_char(date '1900-01-01' + elapsed, 'MI:SS') as minutes
from (
  select bot_id, claim_id,
    process_timestamp - lag(process_timestamp)
      over (partition by bot_id order by process_timestamp) as elapsed
  from your_table
)
where elapsed > 5/1440;

    BOT_ID   CLAIM_ID MINUTES   
---------- ---------- ----------
       123      12346 09:45
```

If it could exceed an hour then you can make the format model `HH24:MI:SS`. (Getting the number of minutes from multiple hours as, say, 120 minutes, is slightly more complicated.)

The filter is now 5/1440 - there are 1440 minutes in a day, so that represents five minutes.

Comment: I do like this, however do the timestamp and the bot id need to be the same datatype?  I am getting inconsistent datatype: expected Date got Number.  Process_Timestamp is datatype date, Bot ID is datatype varchar.  The error is showing at the partition keyword, on this line:  c.process_timestamp - lag(c.process_timestamp, 1, 0) over (partition by u.bot_ID order by c.process_timestamp) as TimeDiff

Comment: Right; you said it was a timestamp. Subtracting dates gives a number (fractions of a day) not an interval, so that number needs to be converted to a string. The `extract()` calls will be throwing that error. Comparing with an interval also won’t work.

Comment: @DorindaMartineau - updated with an example that works with dates. In your comment you have `lag(c.process_timestamp, 1, 0)`; in that construct the `0` is the default to use if there is no previous value, i.e. instead of null. If you actually want that then it needs to be another date, not a number. I'm not sure you do though.

Comment: Alex Poole, thank you very much.  I think I have it working now for the base, and will now work on the rest of the query. This is the first time using lag, but I'm sure it won't be my last, and I can now share this with my team.